# Cordova and sudo in CLI

Tags: cordova, terminal, sudo, cordova-cli

I was looking for a solution for one problem and installed a Cordova plugin with sudo - now I have to use sudo (and write my password) every time I want to build, emulate, or do anything with my project.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody would encounter the same problem, I found a solution: I had to change permissions for the app folder with:

```
$ sudo chmod -R a+rw /directory
```

This command sets the permissions to read&write for everyone.